# AngularDart Batarang alternative

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart, batarang

Do you know any good Angular.dart alternative for Angular.js [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk)? Would be much easier to debug scopes, bindings.

Comment: This is ridiculous. They're not asking for a recommendation, they're asking for a definitive answer about a specific tool.

Answer (score 5):

Currently angular.dart does not offer any graphical debugging tools, however it does provide an introspection API which can be used from Chrome dev tools console.

https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/introspection.dart

Comment: Is there a tutorial on using this? Sounds sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard of any, but would be great.

Comment: Hope a lot of ppl asked it in the Dart survey?

Comment: You should create a feature request https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list